# How to clean cache data of all installed apps in android programmatically in marshmallow version

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

How to clean cache data of all apps in marsmallow.
What are the permissions to be given and how to delete the data?
The code is working below marshmallow, but it is not working from marshmallow.

```
if (mClearCacheObserver == null)
{
    mClearCacheObserver=new CachePackageDataObserver();
}

PackageManager mPM=getPackageManager();

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
final Class[] classes= { Long.TYPE, IPackageDataObserver.class };

Long localLong=Long.valueOf(CACHE_APP);

try
{
    Method localMethod = mPM.getClass().getMethod("freeStorageAndNotify", classes);
    localMethod.setAccessible(true);

    // Start of inner try-catch block
    try
    {
        localMethod.invoke(mPM, localLong, mClearCacheObserver);
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (InvocationTargetException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // End of inner try-catch block
}
catch (NoSuchMethodException e1)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: what is the mistake i have done ...can you please explain me

Answer (score 1):

Just try it :

```
PackageManager  pm = getPackageManager();
    // Get all methods on the PackageManager
    Method[] methods = pm.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method m : methods) {
        if (m.getName().equals("freeStorage")) {
            // Found the method I want to use
            try {
                long desiredFreeStorage = 8 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024; // Request for 8GB of free space
                m.invoke(pm, desiredFreeStorage , null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Method invocation failed. Could be a permission problem
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

You will need to have this in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE"/>
```

Please refer [link](http://www.phonearena.com/news/Android-6.0-Marshmallow-How-to-clear-app-cache-and-data_id79546)

(or)

Try this for one application cache

```
public static void deleteCache(Context context) {
        try {
            File dir = context.getCacheDir();
            if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
                deleteDir(dir);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = dir.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                if (!success) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return dir.delete();
    }
```

Try this also:

```
public static void trimCache(Context context) {
    File dir = context.getCacheDir();
    if(dir!= null && dir.isDirectory()){
        File[] children = dir.listFiles();
        if (children == null) {
            // Either dir does not exist or is not a directory
        } else {
            File temp;
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                temp = children[i];
                temp.delete();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: please tell me another way to clean

Comment: Please check the above my answer, I have update it and try to you